# Email from Apple about Missing Push Notification entitlement

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [App rejected because of “Missing Push Notification Entitlement”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement)

I've just received this email from Apple:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement.

I know that we haven't implemented push notifications in our apps. I need to confirm to the boss that the user wont receive the default "Do you want to register for push notifications?" alert. As it isn't included in the app, they shouldn't see an option to receive, right?

Can't find anything online; has anyone come across this?

Comment: Nope this isnt the same, i know its enabled, but not including, we never realised till now...older project. Just need to know if the user will be asked to register. Which we wish to avoid..

Answer (score 1):

check in the developer portal on the website to see if your app is set up for push notifications, but you just dont remember doing it and are not using it. you can disable it there.

Comment: I know i can disable it, but when the app passes review, will they receive the alert? or will disabling it in the developer portal confirm kill it just incase?

Comment: Disabling it on the developer portal doesn't mean he can't try to register to remove push notification - it just means that the registration will fail and `-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error` will be called.

Comment: the only way they could receive the alert is if you had that in the app along with the updated provisioning profile

Comment: andrei well i figured he didnt put the code in because it doesnt seem like he was aware it was enabled

Comment: Yes Chris this is it exactly, i was assuming that as it isnt in the app, they shouldnt receive the 'please register' alert. Which is what we prefer, we dont want them registering when we havent prepared the backend. Great stuff, whack that in an answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The user will see the alert only when you try to register to remove Push notifications.
So, do you call this (or something similar) in your app?:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];`

If yes then your users will see the alert.
If not then they won't see an alert.