# How to recreate the distribution provisioning profile

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, ios-provisioning, code-signing-entitlements

After submitting my app to the app store (and later it got approved and released) I got an email stating that :

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement...

By [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement) I understand that I need to recreate the profile, and submit the app again resigned with the new profile.

1. How do i recreate the profile ? by editing it and saving, or by deleting it and creating a new one?
2. More importantly - does recreating the profile affect the existing app in the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I was in a hurry to release an update to the app store and couldn't wait for answers. So I took the chance, did it, and found out the answers along the way:

1. In the new provisioning portal, just click edit, and generate (no need any more to change something in order to enable the generate button).
2. No.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is related with push notification.
So are u using push notification in ur app?

If not then u must update the provisioning profile by editing the bundle id.
In developer account go to app ids and uncheck the option of APN in specific appid.
Then update the provisioning profile by selecting that bundle id.