# Invalid Binary: Invalid Launch Image / iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement / Missing Push Notification Entitlement

Tags: ios, iphone-5

My recent version for the app has been rejected as an invalid binary with the following note:

**Invalid Launch Image** - Your app contains a launch image with a size modifier that is only supported for apps built with the iOS 6.0 SDK or later.

Though you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make you aware of them:

**iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement** - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a launch image of the appropriate size. Learn more about iPhone 5 support by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

The app is created to run in **fullscreen** for **iPhone 4-5** and **iPad 1-3** (with and without Retina). The launch images I've created are as such:

```
Default.png (640 x 1136)
Default-568h@2x.png (640 x 1136)
Default@2x~iphone.png (640 x 960)
Default-Portrait~iphone.png (320 x 480)
Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png (1536 x 2008)
Default-Portrait~ipad.png (768 x 1004)
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png (2048 x 1496)
Default-Landscape~ipad.png (1024 x 748)
```

These are in my project root directory and included in the AIR for iOS Settings "Included Files" list in the above order (does order matter?).

When I load the app, the launch images show on both my iPhone 5, and my iPad 3, though they seem to resize/jump a bit to the left on first load, right before switching to the application's home screen. The app is sized correctly on both devices (no black margins).

Perhaps I've misread the sizes. Adobe seems to recommend that I use the full resolution as the image resolutions:

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac58d08f9112e26606ea8-8000

But all other recommendations seem to indicate that the launch images should not include the the menu bar from final dimensions:

- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1588/_index.html

Any advice you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Lastly, Apple's response included the following:

**Missing Push Notification Entitlement** - Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required. You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning. If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the developer for information on removing the API.

In case others are searching on this issue, I was able to resolve with this link:
[App rejected because of "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Comment: This link might help http://rohitdhore1612.wordpress.com/2013/05/22/air-invalid-binary-iphone-5-optimi‌​zation-requirement-your-binary-is-not-optimized-for-iphone-5/

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem as well.  Just fixed in 5 minutes ago actually!  Here is what I did.

Create the following three .png image files and save them to the src folder (don't leave them in the assets folder).

- Default.png (set to 320x480px) - iphone 3
- Default@2x.png (set to 640x960px) - iphone 4
- Default-568h@2x.png (set to 640x1136px) - iphone 5

These files don't have to link to any of your code - Apple uses them to set the initial screen size when loading the app.  Goodluck!

Comment: Don't forget to import them in the project

Answer (score 0):

You are likely developing in a version of XCode that does not include the Base SDK 6.0.  In order to include the iPhone 5 Default-568h@2x.png and not have your app rejected after uploading, you need to build it with a Base SDK pointing to 6.0.  The version of XCode that includes the Base SDK 6.0 drops support for any iOS less than, I think, 4.2, so, if you are targeting devices like the iPhone 3 or first gen iPod, you're out of luck.  If not, then simply update your XCode to the latest version and set the Base SDK in your project's build settings to the latest, or at least 6.0.