# email from Apple - "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"

Tags: ios, push-notification, provisioning-profile

I have been trying to submit an update to my app for 3 days now, and every time that I do I get an email from Apple stating:

> Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include
>   API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the
>   app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement.

I have tried everything that I can, including making brand new provisioning profiles, setting an entitlement.plist and everything that I do results in the same email shortly after submission. I have opened the provisioning profile I am using and it DOES include the aps-entitlement.

Xcode gives me no errors or warnings when I build or archive the app, so everytime I try something new I have to go through the same process.

Is there ANYTHING else I can do to update my app and add push notifications? I have looked at many other questions on here and on google and am tearing my hair out!

**EDIT:**

People continue to think that I haven't looked at other solutions. I have. From the question this has been linked to as already answered, here are the suggestions it makes:

> Re-create the provisioning profile

I have done this. I also made brand new ones. I have verified that they include the aps-environment flag in them.

> Re-create the provisioning profile

Again, I have done this. Many times now.

> Open your Provisioning Profile in any Text Editor and search for
>   "environment" and you must find: aps-environment

The profiles I am using have this.

> Remove calls to the service

Not relevant as I am trying to ADD the service.

> Enable the service and re-create the profile

Again, this has been done.

> Re-create the provisioning profiles

And again.

> Remove the library that is referencing the push notification system

As above, I am adding Push Notification, not looking to remove it as per the question linked here.

I don't want to come off as rude, but please understand that when I say I have spent 3 days looking for answers I am being serious. Not only does this question ask about REMOVING, not adding Push Notifications, I had already added information about trying these methods.

Can someone please help me, or should I just use one of my support tickets with Apple over this?

Comment: Did you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement?rq=1

Comment: I did and I addressed the fixes that it mentions in my original post. Recreating my profiles, verifying the entitlement in a text editor and changing to new profiles has not solved my issue.

Comment: Did you read the part about ensuring the App Id is properly updated with the needed entitlements?

Comment: I did, and it is. I did this before I remade the provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 11):

I have solved this, so here is the answer for others who may come across this in the future.

I had to delete the Entitlements plist I had created when trying to solve the issue earlier in the day, then recreate it through Xcode and add in the same information that was in my provisioning profile. I also had to do this on BOTH the project and the target.

I have not received the email over this submission, and the binary details on iTunes Connect now list "APS Environment: Production".

Thank you to dpassage and maddy who both attempted to help me with the question.

Comment: +1, simply deleting the Entitlements.plist I created fixed the issue.

Comment: can you help me how to delete the Entitlements plist and re-create, I am trying to solve the same issue