# Issues with push notification certificates

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I have accidentally created a new certificate for an existing live app which using push notification.After the upload I got the mail from saying that

> Dear developer, We have discovered one or more issues with your recent
>   delivery for “My App”. Your delivery was successful, but you may wish
>   to correct the following issues in your next delivery: Missing Push
>   Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to include API used to
>   register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
>   signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
>   make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
>   Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
>   Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment"
>   entitlement. See "Provisioning and Development" in the Local and Push
>   Notification Programming Guide for more information. If your app does
>   not use the Apple Push Notification service, no action is required.
>   You may remove the API from future submissions to stop this warning.
>   If you use a third-party framework, you may need to contact the
>   developer for information on removing the API.

*After this mail I have checked BundleID section in developer.apple.com. There push notification is in disabled state.Even after I enabled the push notification checkbox it is in disabled state After pressing done button.Also two certificates are listed there,old one and the one which is recently created.*

*Then I tried to create a new distribution profile,but the old certificates is not listing there.Only the one certificate which  I have recently created is listing there.I got the email from apple after using the profile created with the new certificate.*

I don’t know what to do ? in my application push notification is there.I want to work it like as early.Can any one guide me to create the profile without any issues ?

Comment: you don't add povisioning certificates with enalble push notification.regenerate and add into xcode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App rejected because of "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Comment: there are questions same like your - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658928/email-from-apple-missing-push-notification-entitlement

Comment: They are saying to create new provisioning profile.But in my case while creating profile the certificate which I have used to create pem file is not listing there