# Missing Push Notification Entitlement for iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, xcode-project

I've just uploaded an app to iTunes Connect and got the "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" warning from Apple. My app does not use any API related to push notifications. The warning also included that I do not have the aps-environment entitlement. How do I get rid of this warning? I tried disabling push notifications in the member center and in Xcode (I created a preprocessor macro DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS=1) and still no luck.

EDIT:
I used grep in my project directory to search for couple of strings that could cause this issue. Grep matched the string

> "registerForRemoteNotificationTypes"

in

> ./myProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/myUser.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

I have no idea whether removing the string from this file will change anything because I am unable to upload the app to TestFlight at the moment. I will be thankful if someone has the same issue and tries to fix it by removing the string found by grep (if it's a good idea to edit .xcuserstate files...)

Comment: Have you enabled push notification when you create the bundle id at apple developer account?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing Push Notification Entitlement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807129/missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Comment: possible duplicate of [App rejected because of "Missing Push Notification Entitlement"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251123/missing-push-notification-entitlement/32283844

Answer (score 0):

Try re-create distribution provisioning profile and double check that you do NOT include push notification into list of entitlements

Answer (score 0):

Enable push notification in your bundle Id and recreate provisioning profile .This things work for me.