# What are the certificates I need to upload the push notification apps to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications

Recently I have upload my first app to app store.And my have have push notification. What I did is.

1. I updated all details in iTunes connect
2. I did Archive and first I validate it and I did submit to app store.
3. And after 15 min I got one build in my iTunes connect and I submit for review.

But now my app rejected and I got mail from apple that, my app is registered for push notification. And I saw some solution for that. I need to create some certificate for my push notification enable apps.

But I never create any .cer, .p12 certificate to upload my app store. How to create push notification certificates and what are the other certificate needed to upload my app to app store?

Comment: Why did you add push notifications to your app, and then submit that app, when you have no idea how to use them? If you don't need them then get rid of the relevant push code and settings from your app and resubmit.

Comment: I have added push notification.My app have push notification

Comment: OK so if your app has push notifications then how are you sending the pushes to the app?

Comment: Millions of past questions related such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719182/app-rejected-because-of-missing-push-notification-entitlement

Comment: "I have added push notification.My app have push notification" NO way it can have working push notifications. In order for them to work you would have had to have created certificates by now. So they can't be working so why are they there? which is what I believe Sausage Machine is getting at. Anyway you don't upload certificates to the app store. Check out the duplicate answer and in the future don't be a knob and submit unused and untested functionality in your app to the app store.

Answer (score 0):

All data that you want you will found it here:-
https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial[enter link description here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial)

Answer (score -1):

You first have to create your APNS Certificate in Certificates, Ids and Profiles. You will need a production certificate for submission to App Store. At this stage you will need to create a CSR - Just follow the instructions.

Then download the Certificate and double click on it. It will then be visible in your Keychain Access. Expand the Certificate and it will show a key symbol and it will say private key in the kind column.

Export this private key and save it as ProductionAPNSKey.p12

Then go to your app Id, select Push Notifications and select the APNS Certificate that you created earlier.

This is all you need on the client side. The ProductionAPNSKey.p12 is required in order to send notifications to the client, for example if you use PushSharp then you will need this certificate to show that you are entitled to send push notifications to your app.