# TestFlight push notifications not working

Tags: ios, push-notification, phonegap-build, phonegap, phonegap-pushplugin

**My TestFlight app isn't receiving APNs push notifications**, however my development app receives them correctly. This seems to suggest that it's a problem with my Apple certs/profile/etc. There are numerous SO questions on this topic, but none of them helped me.

I'm using Phonegap Build to build the app -- not Xcode.

I tried regenerating all the certs/profiles/.p12 files, all of which are set up for **distribution** rather than development.

[image]
[image]

In my config.xml, I've set the "aps-environment" entitlement to "production". I've also **confirmed that my provisioning profile contains the aps-environment "production" entitlement**, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14811334/3919052).

```
<config-file target="*.entitlements" parent="aps-environment"> 
    <string>production</string>
</config-file>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regenerated the cert/profile/.p12 about 3 more times and it finally started working. Not a very satisfying answer, but there you go.